# Force page refresh on inner page link

Tags: javascript, html, anchor, reload, page-refresh

I'm trying to link to an inner page anchor and force a refresh of the page.

However this does not force a refresh:

```
<a href="/#example">example link</a>
```

What is the best method of linking to an anchor in the same page AND forcing a refresh?

Also I would like the refresh to be a GET request, even if the page was last rendered with a POST request.

Comment: Are you trying to move page scroll to an element on page load? <a href="somepageurl.html#someelementid">example link</a>

Comment: @AtheistP3ace:  Please read my question; I also want to link within the page AND force a page refresh.

Comment: @HardlyNoticeable yes what I put in comment will load the url and go to the element in page. If the url is the same page you are on it essentially reloads the page.

Comment: I don't know why people downvoted this question.  Web application developers do a lot of URL rewriting now-a-days and this is exactly the kind of issue one may experience when combining URL rewriting with Inner Page Links.

Comment: I hear you. I didn't down vote you. But it drives me nuts when people down vote something and leave no reason why. We can all learn from it possibly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the end, the only thing that seemed to work for me, was to use a combination of window.location and adding a parameter.  So what I ended up doing looked like this:

```
    <p><a href="#example" id="example">Click Here</a></p>
```

and then the following jQuery:

```
    $('#example').click(function(event) {

        window.location = '/?anything#example';

    });
```

I tried adding the parameter directly to the link; but that didn't force a page load; only when adding it using window.location did it seem to work.

Answer (score 5):

Add JS `onClick="window.location.reload()"` event as well to your a tag, full example:

```
<a href="#example" onClick="window.location.reload()">Click to refresh</a>
```

There are a ton of ways to refresh a page with JS, just tie it to your click event. Here are some examples,

```
location = location
location = location.href
location = window.location
location = self.location
location = window.location.href
location = self.location.href
location = location['href']
location = window['location']
location = window['location'].href
location = window['location']['href']
location = window.location['href']
location = self['location']
location = self['location'].href
location = self['location']['href']
location = self.location['href']
location.assign(location)
location.replace(location)
window.location.assign(location)
window.location.replace(location)
self.location.assign(location)
```

Taken from [535 ways to reload a page with JS](http://www.phpied.com/files/location-location/location-location.html).

Comment: I'm trying to go to an anchor link within the page.

Comment: No... it refreshed the page without going to the inner page anchor.

Comment: did you remove ``/`` from the href?

Comment: reload sometimes dont work if an `#` is involve. use history.back(0) to totally refresh the page, which will force the refresh in a browser.

Comment: Okay, What happens if you just used localStorage.clear(); onclick?